# Python K-means fails to fit data when over 100 samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I am very new to `sklearn` (and python in general) but needs to work on some project involving **clustering of over 10k samples**. Using the following code with the test dataset of less than 100 samples with k = 4, the clustering went as expected. However, when I started using more than 100 samples, the **6/8 centroids** appear to be **repeating at the origin (0,0)** i.e. it failed to generate cluster. Any advice for something that could have gone wrong?

Screenshot:
[86 Samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8LmB.jpg),
[150 samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rkre.jpg)

Code:

```
    data = pd.read_csv('parsed.txt', sep="\t", header=None)
    data.columns = ["x", "y"]

    kmeans = KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=1000,
        n_clusters=k, n_init=10, n_jobs=1, precompute_distances='auto',
        random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)
    kmeans.fit(data)

    labels = kmeans.predict(data)
    centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

    fig = plot.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    colmap = {(x+1): [(np.sin(0.3*x + 0)*127+128)/255,(np.sin(0.3*x + 2)*127+128)/255,(np.sin(0.3*x + 4)*127+128)/255] for x in range(k)} # making rainbow colormap
    colors = map(lambda x: colmap[x+1], labels) #color for each label

    plot.scatter(data['x'], data['y'], color=colors, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
    for idx, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
        plot.scatter(*centroid, color=colmap[idx+1])
    plot.xlim(0, 4000)
    plot.ylim(0, 10000)
    plot.show()
```

@ 150 samples, I printed the labels (almost all 2s) and centroid coordinates (most at origins) shown below:

```
[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2]
[[  7.51619277e+09   7.51619277e+09]
 [  1.00000000e+27   1.00000000e+27]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]
```

---

***More details (08/20/17)***

Here are the GIF showing clusters from **k = 1 to 10** for **86 and 150 samples** respectively. As seen here, 86 set works well but not for 150 set which only present at origin. Note that the color change in 150 set at k=4 frame resulted from how I defined colormap, so not a part of the issue.

[image: 86 Samples], [image: 150 Samples]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try checking out first if there actually are so many clusters in your data as you trying to find ? Simply increasing the number of samples does not necessarily mean that the number of clusters will increase as well. If no. of clusters you are giving as input to the algorithm is greater than the actual no. of clusters in the dataset, then it is possible that the algorithm may not converge properly, or the the clusters may simply overlap (completely) over each other.

To find the optimal no. of clusters for your dataset, we use a technique called as elbow method. There are different variations of this method, but the main idea is that for different values of K (no. of clusters) you find the cost function that is most appropriate for you application (Example, Sum of Squared distance of all the points in a cluster to it's centroid for all values of K say 1 to 8, or any other error/cost/variance function. Based on the function you have chosen  , you will see that after a certain point, the difference in the values will be negligible. The idea is that we chose that value of 'K' at which the value of the chosen cost function changes abruptly.

[image: Elbow method]

For the value K=4 the variance is changing abruptly. So K=4 is the chosen to be an appropriate value.

Image Source : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering))

There are several other methods on cluster validation as well. There exists several packages in R specifically for this purpose.

To learn more from the following links :

- [Coursera Lecture on Elbow Method](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/Ks0E9/choosing-the-number-of-clusters)
- [D3js visualization of D3js](https://bl.ocks.org/rpgove/0060ff3b656618e9136b)
- [Quora answer on elbow method](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-choose-a-good-K-for-K-means-clustering)
- [Python implementation of elbow method](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/finding-the-k-in-k-means-clustering/)
- [Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set)

Comment: Thank you, Mohammed. I have never used elbow method so I will learn about that. However for my issue, I made sure to use the same number of cluster k = 4 throughout. The dataset that I use while containing more samples, have very similar characteristics as before. I also tried k = 3 then 2, but the same situation still happened. That was why I was confused.

Comment: if the samples you have added have same characteristics as before then they are more likely to be added to the same clusters obtained using lesser no. of samples. i.e. no new clusters will form. Can you post the results for k=2 and k=3 for 150 and 86 samples ?

Comment: I just updated the post with .gif for k=1->10 for 86 and 150 sets. Yes, I expected about 4-5 very significant clusters in both cases.

Comment: Are you reinitialising the Kmeans object again seperately for 86 and 150 samples ? Also can you try reducing the tolerance attribute and see if there are any changes ? like tol = 0.001,0.1, 0.5, etc. ?

Comment: The two results above were run separately. I tried reducing tolerance to 0.001, 0.1, and 0.5 and still looks the same, work for 86 set but not 150 or more.

Comment: Well, I can't say anything else now unless I can see the data points itself.I am not sure, still as a last effort can you set the 'init' parameter as 'random' instead of k-means++ . It might be the case that randomly selecting the centroids might help. I that still doesn't work, I might need to look at the data if it is possible to replicate the results on my system.

Comment: The bad news is init="random" did not make any difference. However, I did a little experiment. Instead of the currently used samples, I generated random data set at 500 and 1000 samples and it worked! That bring the question to the interaction between my data and kmeans function.

Comment: ^ Updated results in the post. Also, both random sets and my original data sets are all integer values.

Comment: I feel very guilty here... I figured that my original data now works. The reason was because of the data. There were some anomaly of 1e5 magnitude higher that was why the results turned out like that.